# Apply `\enlargethispage' to all document pages

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I'm trying to use `\enlargethispage` on multiple pages, but there is no command like `\enlargepages`.

The pages I need the command for are the ones within I use a customized `\fancypagestyle`. There are several of these pages, so I'm avoiding doing it by hand.

I tried:

```
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
    \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
}
```

but it just works on the first page affected by `\pagestyle{myfancy}`.

MWE (with desired output, but manually achieved, not automatically.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmargins{2.5cm}           
{1.3cm}                    
{15.6cm}                    
{25cm}                 
{10pt}                     
{1cm}                      
{0pt}                      
{1.4cm}

\usepackage{nonumonpart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
    \lfoot{name}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot{\thepage}
    \fancyhead{}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myfancy} 
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[4]\\

blablablablbal ablablablabl abalbalbalba balbalablab ablabalbalba balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala albalabla blablablaba blabalbala balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala


\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[4]\\

\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
blablablablbal ablablablabl abalbalbalba balbalablab ablabalbalba balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala albalabla blablablaba blabalbala balbalba alba ablablaba bla ablab albalabla blablablaba blabalbala

    
\end{document}
```

Display of desired output:

End of page 1
[image: Page 1]

End of page 2
[image: Page 2]

@Mico suggestion of using `\addtolength{\textheight}{2\baselineskip}` destroys the footer and does not add the next lines, so it is not a solution:

End of page 1
[image: Page 1]

End of page 2
[image: Page2]

Comment: How about `\addtolength{\textheight}{2\baselineskip}`?

Comment: @Mico wouldn't `\newgeometry` + `\restoregeometry` be better suited?

Comment: @Skillmon - Since the title of the OP's query contains the requirement "to all document pages", a global approach may be preferable. For sure, though, your approach should work too.

Comment: @Mico, that wouldn't work. See the edit

Comment: @Á.Iborra - So the modificiation is *not" supposed to apply to the entire document? If so, please fix the title of your query.

Comment: @Mico - The modification is supposed to apply to the entire document, but your suggestion is not working as expected. It doesn't include the first lines of the next page, and in the second page, it destroys the footer

Comment: @Á.Iborra did you try setting a bigger text area with `geometry`?

Comment: @Á.Iborra - Where did you place the instruction `\addtolength{\textheight}{2\baselineskip}` -- in the preamble, or in the body of the document`? (If one wants an instruction to have global scope, it needs to be run in the preamble.)

Comment: @Mico - I placed in the preamble, it haven't worked until I've reduced the `\footskip`. Now it works.